# How to handle Qthread termination during app quit()?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, qt, c++11

I've read many stackoverflow answers and a few blog posts(including QThread documentation as well) but I'm still not sure how to handle exiting main app while QThreads are still running(and not crash application meanwhile). What makes this difficult is the fact that those QThread instances contain different sorts of blocking functions such as curl queries, c++ file io, etc. Making it hard to use isInterruption requested API(which I would've used in an ideal case). To top that, I've to make sure these work fine across Linux, Windows, and OSX. We can assume here any file io corruption or incomplete network queries don't worry us and are taken care of. Here is the whole working example [zipped](https://0x0.st/iU3j.zip). I use Qthreads in two different ways, which I'll demonstrate here, and the general idea is to bind application's `aboutToQuit()` with thread's `terminate()` assuming that this is safe since the app is going to close anyway -

---

1. Worker/Controller

   ```
    class Worker : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public slots:
        void doWork(const QString &msg) { QThread::sleep(10); emit resultReady("Finished"); }  // simulates thread doing work
    signals:
        void resultReady(const QString &result);
    };

    class Controller : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        QThread workerThread;
    public:
        Controller() {
            Worker *worker = new Worker;
            worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
            connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
            connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
            connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
            connect(QCoreApplication::instance(), SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), this, SLOT(terminateThread()));
            workerThread.start();
        }
        ~Controller() { workerThread.quit(); workerThread.wait(); }
    public slots:
        void handleResults(const QString &msg);
        void terminateThread() { workerThread.terminate(); workerThread.wait(); }
    signals:
        void operate(const QString &msg);
    };

    // can be started like
    Controller c;
    emit c.operate("Starting Thread");
   ```

---

2. Method run() override

   ```
    class WorkerThread : public QThread
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        void run() override { QThread::sleep(10); emit resultReady("Finished");}

        signals:
        void resultReady(const QString &s);

    public slots:
        void terminateThread() { workerThread.terminate(); workerThread.wait(); }
    };

    class MyObject : public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT

    public slots:
        void handleResults(const QString &msg);
    public:
        void startWorkInAThread() {
            WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread();
            connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::resultReady, this, &MyObject::handleResults);
            connect(workerThread, &WorkerThread::finished, workerThread, &QObject::deleteLater);
            connect(QCoreApplication::instance(), SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), workerThread, SLOT(terminateThread()));
            workerThread->start();
        }
    };

    // can be started like
    MyObject obj;
    obj.startWorkInAThread();
   ```

---

and I test both of these methods using main() that looks like -

```
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::puts("Starting app");
    //    Controller c;
    //    emit c.operate("Starting Thread");

    MyObject obj;
    obj.startWorkInAThread();

    QTimer::singleShot(2000, [&]{
        std::puts("Quit pressed");
        a.quit();
    });
    return a.exec();
```

---

Now the issues -

1. If I use Controller method, Linux gives some error message about exception not being caught while exiting. That message goes away if I remove .wait() calls but those are supposedly necessary. Windows exits fine but the return code is some negative large number. OSX crashes the application, maybe due to .wait() call.

   ```
    Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
    exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt.
    You must not let any exception whatsoever propagate through Qt code.
    If that is not possible, in Qt 5 you must at least reimplement
    QCoreApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

    (process:3416): GLib-CRITICAL **: 22:45:51.656: g_source_unref_internal: assertion 'source != NULL' failed
   ```
2. If I use run() overriding, Linux works perfectly fine and so does OSX. On Windows the program never finishes, stuck on .terminate() call or if I remove that then on .wait() call.
3. There are also some usages(in actual application, not in given examples) where the run() overriding is used but the run method's owner class is initialized as - `WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread(this);` and due to `this` being setup as it's parent, it crashes the program on exit somehow.
4. I actually don't want to wait on threads and want them to exit asap when my program quits, some blocking network operations could take several minutes to complete.

---

I suppose I've explained everything in detail but to summarize, I want my app to quit gracefully with running background threads and not crash at all. And do this on all supported(mentioned) QT platforms.

Comment: If you want some general way to stop thread & not to wait & not to crash & not to do anything for correct stop blocking operations & IN the same time - it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

In your example project, just replace `workerThread.terminate()` by `workerThread.quit()` in the `Controller::terminateThread()` method.

The usage of `QThread::terminate()` is described as [dangerous and discouraged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) in the Qt documentation. Using `QThread::quit()` allow the worker thread event loop to gently handle this after his long work (sleep).

As you said, the best way to make long running tasks cleanly interruptible should be to use the `QThread::requestInterruption` system and check during long operation if an interruption is requested.

Comment: The reason why I can't use `QThread::requestInterruption` and friends is that my code contains blocking calls. I can't check for interruption while these blocking calls are running and when these are long enough(say a curl upload call that takes 2 minutes to upload a file), then quitting in between results in crash(if termination is used) or program doesn't quits till 2 minutes pass and upload finally finishes.
So replacing terminate() with quit() doesn't really help for my case since quit() makes the program not quit.

Comment: If your code use blocking calls, then there is no way to cleanly quit your thread the way you want it to.

Every async services should have a progress notification for long tasks (e.g. percentage of progression for a curl upload) and a way to cancel it. At each notification of progress, the service could check `QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested()` and if requested, clean itself before quitting.

Comment: You're right that curl does have an async interface, I still can't use it because of how widespread it already is used with synchronous api. Then there are file io operations that are sync again. Few more libraries that are sync. I wish there were async api to each one of those but that's why I posted this question.